# IR remote control interfacing PIC16f877a

Tags: microcontroller, pic, remote-control

I have TSOP1738 and PIC16f887a, 4mH. I want to do something which is:

- if I push button '2', led1 should work.
- if I push button '4', led2 should work.

I just simply thought a method but couldn't succeed. I found my remote controller buttons' addresses. For example the address of button '2' is `0XFF18E7` and I made this :

```
if(input(pin_a0) == 0xFF18E7){
    output_b(0b00000001);
    delay_ms(500);
}
```

By the way, I connected output pin of TSOP1738 to pin_a0 and connected led to `pin_b0`.

I think pins work only 1 or 0 and do not see that address as I tried.
How can I interface my remote controller with PIC?
Which way should I follow?
I don't know interrupt method, is there any way except interrupt?

(I have term project, I just trying this remote controller to see if it works or not. I will then use that on a DC motor action)

Comment: We need a wiring diagramm and your code if you want help.

Comment: The website wants at least 10 reputation so I could not upload image of my simulation and wiring diagram picture. Could you share your email address so I can mail you image

Comment: It looks like aß you wants to read a 24bit value on a single pin.

Comment: I use TSOP1738 and don't know if it is 32 or 24 bit, which way do you suggest me to follow and I can mail pin connections diagram in my circuit.

Comment: You can only read one Bit from a pin otherwise you need something like SPI or UART. Look into the datasheet.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I found a solution which is ready to go on this website link, https://simple-circuit.com/pic16f877a-nec-remote-control-decoder/

Comment: https://www.sbprojects.net/knowledge/ir/index.php  much better link.  Yes pretty easy to use one of those receivers and an mcu to decode a remote.  I actually did my first with a pic but then have repeated it many times.  Fun beginner project. not all remotes are nec, a lot arent.  some protocols are easier than others.   NEC and others that have a sync pattern up front are easier than ones that are just biphase/manchester encoded.

Comment: you have to decode the protocol then from that take the value decoded and then if-then-else your way to which led you want to light up.  if you simply tie the output of the receiver to an led either through software or directly through a resistor you will just get the led to blink in visible light what is happening in IR

Comment: which in and of itself isnt a bad first task in software